# Console Background color doesn't reset

Tags: c#, terminal, console, .net-8.0, console.writeline

Even with Console.ResetColor(); it still doesn't reset after the last line

```cs
if (Total >= 15)
{
    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    Console.WriteLine("You win");
    
    if (Total - 15 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You won without any extra points, :)");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"You won with {Total - 15} extra points, :)");
    }
    
    Console.ResetColor();
}
else
{
    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    Console.WriteLine("You lost");
    Console.WriteLine($"You were {15 - Total} points away, :(");
    Console.ResetColor();
}

Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
Console.ResetColor();
```

Resetting the color on the if statements apart and also changing the background color to black but does nothing as well.

Tested in the PowerShell terminal if that helps.

Comment: Can't replicate your error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWdxi.png

Comment: Consider sharing your whole application, since it seems the error is located somwhere else.

Comment: note: "Windows-Terminal" is a windows store app, so consider checking which version you have installed and maybe update to the latest: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U62yi.png (don't think its a bug of the version you have, but you never know)

Answer (score 1):

apparently restarting my pc did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
if (Total >= 15)
{
   Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
   Console.WriteLine("You win");

   if (Total - 15 == 0)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("You won without any extra points, :)");
   }
   else
   {
       Console.WriteLine($"You won with {Total - 15} extra points, :)");
   }

   Console.ResetColor();
}
else
{
   Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
   Console.WriteLine("You lost");
   Console.WriteLine($"You were {15 - Total} points away, :(");
   Console.ResetColor();
}

Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
Console.ResetColor();
```

Comment: doesn't work either

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**